# Converting a HTML/CSS/JS Mapbox File to React

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Hey i am working on a project and am required to convert it to react. Does anyone know how to convert a mapbox project in HTML/CSS/JS into React? All my attempts have failed and i am beginning to stress out.

This is the file I am trying to Reactify

````
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Change a map's style</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.3.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.3.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
<style>
#menu {
position: absolute;
background: #fff;
padding: 10px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

</style>

<div id='map'></div>
<pre id='info'></pre>
<script>
var bounds = [
[-135, 13], // Southwest coordinates
[-63, 50]  // Northeast coordinates
];
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYnNvZ2hpZ2lhbiIsImEiOiJjazBhOTUxam4wMDNtM2RvNXJzbjQ5aGV6In0.eL8NJ0-ikx_5Dl49994bGw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',//id of the div you use for the canvas
style: 'mapbox://styles/bsoghigian/ck0eubu3v0wzj1cp3eu3khs2e',//This is where you put your custom style url
zoom: 13,//How zoomed in or out of the map you are
center: [-97, 50],//Point of origin. Where your map begins in longitude and lattitude
pitch: -60, // pitch in degrees
bearing: 0, // bearing in degrees
zoom: 1,
maxBounds: bounds
});

map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
mapboxgl: mapboxgl
}));



</script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: I would like to avoid using react-map-js or the other wrappers bc we are gonna be working on a really advanced program and will require the entire functionality of the Mapbox-gl Api.

Comment: Can you include the React code you are working with? What have you tried that is not working?